# How to upload image using Backendless in swift 3.0

Tags: swift3, uiimagepickercontroller, backendless

I am working on swift 3.0 uisng backendless. I am new to this concept. I am uploading image which I am selecting from the phone gallery using UIImagePickerController. In back endless I am using Rest Api. I am uplaoding the image using the following code ..

```
 public func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
    {
        let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
        self.uploadButton.isHidden = true
        myImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
       myImageView.image = image


        let imageUrl          = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as! NSURL
        let imageName         = imageUrl.lastPathComponent
        let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first!
        let photoURL          = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: documentDirectory)
        let localPath         = photoURL.appendingPathComponent(imageName!)

        print(localPath!)


        let imageurl = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? NSURL
        let imagename = imageurl?.lastPathComponent
        print(imagename!)

         //https://api.backendless.com/<application id>/<version name>/files/<path>/<file name>

        Alamofire.request(“https://api.backendless.com/66B90F83-A813-84CF-FF9D-4A01AC28E100/v1/files/ + "\(localPath!)/\(imagename!)", method: .post, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: HeadersClass.allHeaders.headers).responseJSON { response in
            debugPrint(response)
        }

        imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

> But I am getting the “Status Code error = 400”.

Can anyone please tell me what mistake I did here. 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: why are you not using their libraries? https://backendless.com/documentation/files/ios/files_file_upload.htm

Comment: I used that Api only for that only I ma getting 400 status code error

Comment: no, you are trying to send that via alamofire by requesting address that does not exists, how the backendless server have to know about your file local path? use what they did to upload file, you have section for that

Comment: If I want to upload image dynamically using app means how?

Answer (score 0):

Your are totally wrong from first step. 
The request url you made is the return url that the backendless service will return back to you when you uploaded your file successfully.

regarding to backendless service, https://backendless.com/documentation/files/ios/files_file_upload.htm, you need to implement the functions that listed down here:

```
// Upload data block identified as 'content' to the specified path.
// If the server returns an error, it is delivered through
// the 'responder' object
func upload(_ path: String,
            content content: NSData,
            responder responder: IResponder!) -> Void

// Upload data block identified as 'content' to the specified path.
// If the file already exists on the server, overwrite if the
// 'overwrite' argument is set to YES/TRUE.
// If the server returns an error, it is delivered through
// the 'responder' object
func upload(_ path: String,
            content content: NSData,
            overwrite overwrite: Bool,
            responder responder: IResponder!) -> Void

// Upload data block identified as 'content' to the specified path.
// If the server returns an error, it is delivered through
// the 'error' block-based callback
func upload(_ path: String,
            content content: NSData,
            response responseBlock: ((BackendlessFile!) -> Void)!,
            error errorBlock: ((Fault!) -> Void)!) -> Void

// Upload data block identified as 'content' to the specified path.
// If the file already exists on the server, overwrite if the
// 'overwrite' argument is set to YES/TRUE.
// If the server returns an error, it is delivered through
// the 'error' block-based callback
func upload(_ path: String,
            content content: NSData,
            overwrite overwrite: Bool,
            response responseBlock: ((BackendlessFile!) -> Void)!,
            error errorBlock: ((Fault!) -> Void)!) -> Void
```

More detail, you can read in their document.

Comment: I used the "Upload function" but How can i see the image which I have sent?